# how to set default value in dropdownlist based on another dropdown selected item

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a basic html form,when the page loads it loads the form to initial values with no data.

in a single page i have added two tab containers left side grid and right side is html form

what ever the records that are loaded in the grid when we double click on that it will fill the right side form.

My requirement is based on one type dropdown selected value how can i get the default value in product  dropdown.

for eg : i have a column in the left side grid type with data Fab..when we doubleclick on this row the form will be filled with selected value
Fab. when the selected value in type dropdown is fab i need to check null or empty values in product dropdown column and set default value.

The values which we get in dropdownlist for product is

```
NULL
NULL
SH_TY
HG_IU
NULL
NULL
```

The values which we get in dropdownlist for type is

```
Fab
LOI
TYU
Swa
```

This is the code we are trying to fill the form

Here are the column names

```
var formFields = [ 
{column: 'ProductTypeId'},
{column: 'ProductCodeID'},],

    var fillForm = function (record) {
                for (var i in formFields) {
                    if (formFields[i].column != null) {
                        var currentValue = record[formFields[i].column];
                        var initValue = record[formFields[i].column + "_init"];
                        formFields[i].ref.set('value', (currentValue == null) ? '' : currentValue);

if (formFields[i].column == 'BtDate') {
                            formFields[i].ref.set('value', (currentValue == null || currentValue == '0') ? '0' : '1');
                        }

I tried to check like this but not working

 if (formFields[i].column == 'ProductTypeId') {
                       if(currentValue == "Fab" || currentValue == "Swa")
                          {
                 formFields[i].ref.set.column.ProductCodeID('value', (currentValue == null || currentValue == '' || currentValue == currentValue) ? 'A_CL_FA': currentValue);
                        }
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use a property for way selected your dropdownlist by value differ of the null.

Comment: I didnt understood ,My ProductTypeId field is filtering select type.